# Use multiple commands in a single keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, hdmi

I would like to associate these two commands with two keyboard shortcuts to activate and quickly deactivate the television connected to the PC as if it were a second monitor.

To activate TV monitor and audio:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --right-of DVI-0; pacmd set-default-sink 1
```

To turn off:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off; pacmd set-default-sink 0
```

The commands in the terminal work, but as I associate them with a keyboard shortcut they stop working.

Ideas on how to solve? why does this happen?

Comment: Cant you try adding && between the commands?

Comment: /bin/bash -c "command_1 && command_2", must be a dupe of something.

Comment: @JacobVlijm for sure it will, but try for yourself searching "multiple commands single keyboard shortcut". It is not always easy to find matching duplicates.

Comment: @vanadium sure! it's not a reproof, I just can't search atm on the phone. So a +1 from me to the answer and the question.

Comment: I see 4 separate commands there.  You might want to see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152659/bash-sh-difference-between-and showing that `;` and `&&` are used to run separate commands on the same line. I believe that in your new shortcut that you use you can put them all into a single line command by adding a `;` between both of your lines making them 1 line.

Comment: @Terrance two commands are for two shortcut keys, one to enable TV screen and audio, and the second to disable.

Comment: @JacobVlijm also upvoting the question: it is concise, straightforward and well documented with a title that reflects the actual question.

Comment: @vanadium I see that now, thanks!  However, it is still 4 separate commands regardless.

Comment: @Terrance, did a small edit so it is clear at first glance ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only a single command indeed can be entered into the shortcut definition dialog. Two workarounds are 1) call a script that contains the commands and 2) use the construct `sh -c "..."`.

In your case with only two commands, option 2 is simplest:

```
sh -c "xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off; pacmd set-default-sink 1"
```

Comment: I still have to test it properly, but for the moment the second option is working! I happily accept your solution!

Comment: Thank you very much for improving the readability of my question, but I had to edit the question as the activation and deactivation commands were reversed .. :)